# Revolution of two curves around the y-axis

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I've looked through the other posts on rotating a function around the x or y axis and haven't had any luck.

my question is this how do i rotate the area between the functions $f(x)=x^2+1$, and $f(x)=2x^2-2$, whereby $x>0$ and $y>0$ and the region is bounded by the y and x axis.

This is a plot of the area I'm talking about.

[image]

Revolving the area around the y-axis is suppose to produce a vase, although I picture something of a shallow bowl.

Any help would be much appreciated. As I'm still quite new to *Mathematica*, an explanation of any code posted would be helpful.

Comment: Please include the code you are trying in your question

Comment: RevolutionPlot3D[{x^2 + 1, 2 x^2 - 2}, {x, 0, Sqrt[3]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, RevolutionAxis -> "Y"]    this is the code I'm trying but its not giving me what i know it should look like

Comment: `RevolutionPlot3D[{fx,fz},{t,t0,t1}]` generates a plot of the surface obtained by rotating the **parametric curve with x,z coordinates** {fx, fz} around the z axis. So your input created a very different curve from what `Plot` shows. Check the documentation very carefully.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer but an extended comment on belisarius' answer.

I think the plot will look more like what I believe the OP is expecting if a few options are added.

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[#, {x, 0, Sqrt[3]},
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0., Automatic}},
  MeshStyle -> None,
  Axes -> None,
  Boxed -> False,
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]] & /@ 
    {2 x^2 - 2, x^2 + 1, Piecewise[{{0, 0 < x < 1}}, Null]}]
```

[image: plot]

Also note that I have put a bottom on the bowl.

Answer (score 3):

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[#, {x, 0, Sqrt[3]}, MeshStyle -> None, 
                      PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]] & /@ {2 x^2 - 2,  x^2 + 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: shouldn't it have a flat bottom as the domain of this pair of functions is restricted to x>0 and y>0 ?

Comment: @errymerry I believe you can work that out easily by yourself ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just for something different:

```
pp = ParametricPlot3D[{Sqrt[3] Cos[t], Sqrt[3] Sin[t], 4}, {t, 0, 
    2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.04]}, Boxed -> False];
rp = RegionPlot3D[
   0 < x^2 + y^2 < 3 && 
    Max[0, 2 x^2 + 2 y^2 - 2] < z < x^2 + y^2 + 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2,
     2}, {z, 0, 5}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 200,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Boxed -> False];
Show[pp, rp, Axes -> False, Background -> Black]
```

Top ring just to deal with boundary of intersection...

[image]